# Extract cloudant document in java

Tags: java, cloudant

I received response from cloudant and I want parse the response.

My response is,

```
{"_id":"id_name_list","_rev":"5-9e6b089e3094955395d1c976c5d87392","1":"aa","2":"bb","3":"cc","4":"dd"}
```

Code to convert response to JSON is,

```
 JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
 String s = jo.get("1");
```

I am getting the error:

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["1"] not found.

Comment: You should rather use `Object s = jo.get("1");` or `String s = jo.getString("1");`

Comment: You are right. But I don't think that the error message would be "JSONObject["1"] not found", if the error was in using wrong method.

Comment: @sridhar Is your response a String?

Comment: What implementation of `JSONObject` are you using?

Comment: My response was StringBuffer. I converted that to string. It is working now